# How to remove curly braces from keys of associative array using php?

Tags: php, arrays

I want the value of `contact_firstname`. Following is the output.

```
Array 
( 
    [{contact_firstname}] => C Client 
    [{contact_lastname}] => N New 
    [{contact_email}] => cn.clientnew@gmail.com 
    [{client_company}] => 
    [{client_phonenumber}] => 34567 
    [{client_country}] => Finland 
    [{client_city}] => dfgh 
    [{client_zip}] => 9876 
    [{client_state}] => wb 
    [{client_address}] => sdfghjk 
    [{password}] => 
    [{client_vat_number}] => 
    [{bank_details}] => BANQUE : DEUTSCHE BANK BENEFICIARY NAME: ZWIEFKA Gmbh IBAN : DE14 8707 0024 0827 1595 00 SWIFT/BIC : DEUTDEDBCHE ADDRESS: DARIUSZ MIKOLAJCZYK, LANDESKRONSTR. 02826 GORLITZ DEUTSCHLAND 
    [{client_id}] => 5 
    [{country_short}] => FI 
)
```

Comment: Instead of trying to cure the symptom you should fix the cause. So what creates such structure?

Comment: I hope this is not real bank data that you have posted on the internet :)

Answer (score -1):

Use simple `foreach` loop and in loop remove `{}` from key name using `trim()` and then create new item with new key name. At the end remove old key using `unset()`.

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$item){
    $array[trim($key, "{}")] = $item;
    unset($array[$key]);   
}
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/ZCU73)

Comment: what you use `trim()` for here? also changing array you iterate over is not the best idea to have. You should create new array or at least iterate over result of `array_keys()`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Did you readed question? She want remove `{}` from keys of array. Also there isn't any problem in changing array in foreach because i remove an item and add new item to array.

Comment: that's why you should use `array_keys()` and not rely on array implementation. Keys manipulation may affect element order, which `array_keys()` shields you from